# Copy a specific cell on all sheets to master sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have a master sheet with the format as below:
Master sheet

```
Column A          Column B         Column C
No                Description        Price
```

And multiple sheets with the format below:

Sheet 1

```
          Column A           Column B
Row 1     Company Name       ABC
Row 2     Delivered to       XYZ
Row 3     Description        ABCXYZ
Row 4     Delivered date     2014
Row 5     Price              $5
```

Sheet 2

```
          Column A           Column B
Row 1     Company Name       ABC
Row 2     Delivered to       XYZ2
Row 3     Description        TestDesc
Row 4     Delivered date     2014
Row 5     Price              $50
```

Now, I want the master sheet auto getting value from sheets into the master sheet like below:
Master sheet

```
Column A          Column B         Column C
No                Description        Price
1                 ABCXYZ              $5        (value from sheet 1)
2                 TestDesc            $50       (value from sheet 2)
```

Would you please to show me how to write vba code to do this update automatically. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without VBA. You can use the following formulas for all rows in column B and C of your master sheet;

`=INDIRECT(" 'sheet " & ROW()-1 & " '! " & " B3 ")`

`=INDIRECT(" 'sheet " & ROW()-1 & " '! " & " B5 ")`

This is assuming that your sheet names are sheet1, sheet2 and so on. If this is not the case, simply replace `'sheet " & ROW()-1` with something that matches the names of your sheets. To make it more dynamic you could use the following formula to search for corresponding fields based on the header in your master sheet;

`=VLOOKUP(B$1, INDIRECT("'sheet"&ROW()-1&"'!"&"A:B"), 2, FALSE)`